# Solve the equation $ z^2 + \left\vert z \right\vert = 0 $, where $z$ is a complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

I've tried solving this, but I'm stuck at one point.

Here's what I did:

Let $ z = x + yi $, where $x, y \in \mathbf R$

Then , $ (x + yi)^2 + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 0 $

Or, $x^2 + {(yi)}^2 + 2xyi + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 0 $

Or, $ x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 0 + 0i$

Thus, $ x^2 - y^2 + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ (i)$
and $2xy = 0 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(ii)$

If $2xy = 0$, then either $x = 0 $ or $y = 0$

Now, if I take $ x = 0$, and subsitute in $(i)$, I get either $y = 0$ or $y  = 1$.

So far, so good, but if I take $y = 0$, and substitute in $(ii)$:

We have $x^2 + \sqrt{x^2} = 0$

so $x^2 = -\sqrt{x^2} $

or $x^2 = -x$

or $\frac{x^2}{x} = -1 $

or $x = -1$

However, this solution doesn't satistfy the equation $x^2 + \sqrt{x^2}$ or the original equation.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Why do you have $+y^2$ in (i)? Shouldn't it be $-$?

Comment: Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, then
$r^2e^{2i\theta}+r=r(re^{2i\theta}+1)=0\iff r=0\text{ or }re^{2i\theta}+1=0$. Solve and reconstruct your complex numbers from $r$ and $\theta$. The trivial solution is $z=0$ (corresponding to $r=0$)...

Comment: Apart from the obvious solution $z=0$, $|z|$ is always a positive real. That maske $z^2$ a negative real and $z=iy$ purely imaginary. The equation becomes $-y^2+|y|=0$ and as $y^2=|y|^2$, this leads to $|y|=1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't understand the bit about $z^2$ being a negative real. How does $\left\vert z \right\vert$ being a positive real make $z^2$ a negative real ?

Answer (score 1):

In $x^2 = -\sqrt{x^2}$, note that $x$ is real, so you have a non-negative on the left, and a non-positive on the right. Therefore they must both be $0$.

Alternative solution:
$$
z^2=-|z|\\
|z|^2=|z|\\
|z|=0\quad \text{or}\quad|z|=1
$$
then for $|z|=1$, solve $z^2+1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R};\;z=x+iy$ the given equation $z^2+|z|=0$ becomes

$(x+iy)^2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0$

$x^2-y^2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+ixy=0$

which translates in the system

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x^2-y^2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0 \\
 y-2 x y=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x^2-y^2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0 \\
 2xy=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

Which splits into two systems

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x^2-y^2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0 \\
 x=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$
$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x^2-y^2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0 \\
 y=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 -y^2+\sqrt{y^2}=0 \\
 x=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$
$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x^2+\sqrt{x^2}=0 \\
 y=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 y^2=|\,y\,| \\
 x=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$
$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x^2=-|\,x\,| \\
 y=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 y=0\lor y= \pm 1 \\
 x=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$
$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x=0\\
 y=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

So we have the solutions

$z=0\lor z=\pm i$

Hope this helps